# Google Search bar for Google.com not custom site?

Tags: html, search

Where can I find the HTML to add Google search that searches the web just like Google and not a custom website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a text box, and on submit, just replace the spaces in the text with a `+` and tack it on the end of `https://www.google.com/search?q=`

```
This is a test
```

becomes

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=This+is+a+test
```